# Why do I get these errors with my ternary operator?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, conditional-statements, conditional-operator

This is what I get in the console: `Unnecessary use of boolean literals in conditional expression  no-unneeded-ternary.`

I'm just trying to do a ternary operator that validates the state of a game and only if the game has started and the user.role is equal with player I disable the button. I am using reactjs and with the help of FormField hook I am making a form.

```
disabled ={(game.state === 'started' && user.role === PLAYER) ? true : false}
```

Comment: `game.state === 'started' && user.role === PLAYER` already evaluates to a boolean value.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The ternary operator is unnecessary:

```js
disabled ={(game.state === 'started' && user.role === PLAYER)}
```

Comment: Thank u ! Now I get this : TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'state')

Comment: @Joe It means `game` is `undefined`.

Answer (score 0):

No need to use statements in this case, ESlint is letting you know it's redundant since the value produced from this statement is already a boolean and you can create a simpler code.

Just write:

```
disabled = {(game.state === 'started' && user.role === PLAYER)}
```